# Flutter - TextFormField, onChanged doesn't appear to be updating value

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm having an issue with the use of a `TextFormField` in Flutter.
The method called in the initial value returns either `null` or a String depending on whether an add or edit screen is being used respectively.
If it is an edit screen I'd like the String to be the initial value, and the `_itemName` to be the initial value if it is not changed, or the new `onChanged` value if it is.

Below shows two of many attempts that I've made that have presented different problems.

In this case if the user does not edit the text the `_itemName` ends up being `null` or a zero length string (I can't remember exactly which one it is):

```
TextFormField(
            initialValue: controller.initialNameValue(),            
            onChanged: (val) {
              setState(() => _itemName = val);
            }),
```

In this case the `onChanged` method does not update the `_itemName` and it remains at its initial value:

```
TextFormField(
            initialValue: _itemName = controller.initialNameValue(),            
            onChanged: (val) {
              setState(() => _itemName = val);
            }),
```

The `_itemName` is then used in an add or edit method where it is passed as a parameter into a setter for a class.

How would I go about ensuring the `_itemName` remains as its initial value until it's changed, and then when it is changed it updates to the new value? Thanks

Comment: Refer [Handle changes to a text field](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/text-field-changes) example from flutter docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trial and error I've realised the way of overcoming this problem seems to be to introduce:

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _itemName = controller.initialNameValue();
  }
```

And then change the TextFormField to:

```
TextFormField(
          onChanged: (val) {
            setState(() => _itemName = val);
          },
          initialValue: controller.initialNameValue(),
);
```

The main reason for not introducing a separate controller here was due to the fact I had multiple form fields within the widget I was building, and this created further confusion.

The above approach appears to have solved the issues that I faced, although I understand it may not be the cleanest approach to this.